# Sending email to users in php codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, verification

Here I have a form to add staff and  I need to send an email to each user, after admin adds a new user,and provide url to redirect the user to login page and able them to login with default password(123), I have written below codes , but nutting is happening , can anyone give me the idea of what I am missing?
Here is my controller

```
 function add()
    {
      //print_r($_REQUEST);
    // die;
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('Uname', 'User Name', 'required');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('Fname', 'First Name', 'required');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('Lname', 'Last Name' , 'required');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('Mobno', 'Mobile No', 'required');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('Email', 'Email' , 'required');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('Emp_id', 'Employee Id' , 'required');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('Status', 'Status' , 'required');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('role', 'Role', 'required');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('Subcom', 'Sub Company' , 'required');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('manager', 'manager' , 'required');

      
      $data['staff'] = $this->staff_model->getStaffDetails();
      $data['role_name'] = $this->staff_model->getAllRole();
      $data['company_name'] = $this->staff_model->getAllCompanyName();
      // print_r($_REQUEST);
      //  die;

      if ($this->form_validation->run() ==true)
      {
        
        $this->staff_model->add(); 


         
       $email = $this->staff_model->sendEmailToUser($this->input->post('email'));
        // print_r($_REQUEST);
        // die;
        if($email)  
      {
          $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'A confirmation email has been sent to ' . $email );
          redirect('admin/staff/index');
          
      } else {
          show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
          redirect('admin/staff/index');
      }
 

        

          
        $this->session->set_flashdata ('success','Staff Added Sucessfully');

        redirect('admin/staff/index',$data);
      }
      else{
        $this->load->view('admin/staff/add',$data);
      }

 
    }
```

Here is the staff_model.php

```
function sendEmailToUser($email)
 {
 $this->load->library('email');
 $config = Array(
 'protocol' => 'smtp',
 'smtp_secure' => 'mail',
 'smtp_host' => 'mail.admin.com.my',
 'smtp_port' => 587,
 'smtp_user' => 'contactus@admin.com.my', 
 'smtp_pass' => '*****', 
 'mailtype' => 'html',
 'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
 'wordwrap' => TRUE,
 '_smtp_auth' => TRUE

  );

  $this->email->initialize($config);
  $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
  $this->email->from('contactus@admin.com.my', "Admin Team");
  $this->email->to($email);  
  $this->email->subject("Confirmation Email ");
  $this->email->message("Dear User,\nPlease click on below URL or paste into your browser to Login\n\n http://localhost:8080/ASGB/admin"."\n"."\n\nThanks\nAdmin Team");
  // <a href='.base_url('login').$email.'/'$password'>Click Here</a>'); 

 $result  = $this->email->send();
 if($result){

 }else{
  print_r($this->email->print_debugger());die;
 }
 //var_dump($result  = $this->email->send());
 

  }
```

Comment: Did you try to `var_dump` the return value of the email `send()` method? e.g. `var_dump($result  = $this->email->send());`

Comment: I think you forgot to **initialize** your $config as follows `$this->email->initialize($config);`

Comment: I updated my code and now getting error :`from: 250 OK
to: 501 <>: missing or malformed local part
The following SMTP error was encountered: 501 <>: missing or malformed local part
quit: 221 lekor.mschosting.com closing connection
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.`

Comment: so your code works but your smtp doesn't , use mailtrap for testing

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean? and how I should do it? I am kinda new to this @MalikMudassar

Comment: you are calling $this->staff_model->sendEmailToUser($email, $password); where is $email and $password initialized ?

Comment: I updated the code please have a look

Comment: I still couldn't solve the issue , Any help please ? @MalikMudassar

Comment: any error returned from debugger?